# dropdown selection will not work with text only numbers used in JS for calculation of total

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I have a form that only captures following fields.(see below) I need to revise it, so that field "formdesc" (form description) captures what was selected in the dropdown as text only. But now there is an options id = [0, 1, 2,3] that are used for price point in JS to calculate total ammount purchased.

HTML:

```
   <form action="http://" method="get" name="form">
   <input id="forminv" type="hidden" name="forminv" value="StudentOrg"> (fixed value)
   <input id="formbal" type="hidden" name="formbal" value="0"> (this pulls total from id=tot)
   <input type="text" name="formfname"> (this pulls first name)
   <input type="text" name="formlname"> (this pulls last name)
   <type="text" name="formid"> (this for a student number)
   <select id="apparelType" name="formdesc"> (this should pull value from selection)
   <option selected value="na">Select</option>
   <option value="0">T-Shirt</option> (I need to change this value to “shirt”)
   <option value="1">Shorts</option> (here too, but can't work with JS below)
   <option value="2">Hat</option> (here too)
   <option value="3">Bag</option> (here too)
   <input id="numb" type="number" name="formterm"> (this pulls quantity, and changes total)
   <id="tot"<Total: $0.00&nbsp;>
   <input type="submit" value=" Make a Credit Card Payment">
   </form>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#numb').keyup(function () {
        var appVal = new Array();
        appVal[0] = 15; (if I change this, stops working)
        appVal[1] = 20;
        appVal[2] = 25;
        appVal[3] = 30;
        var cost = 0;
        var fmapVal = $('#apparelType').val();
        if (fmapVal == 'na') {
            alert('Please select an apparel type.');
        } else {
            cost = appVal[fmapVal];
        };
        //alert(cost);
        var getNumb = $('#numb').val();
        var baseTotal = cost * getNumb;
        var getTax = baseTotal * .06;
        var getTotal = baseTotal + getTax;
        $('#tot').html('Total: $' + etTotal.toFixed(2));
        $('#formbal').val(getTotal.toFixed(2));
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you want to get the selected item's text..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is working **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e5aGx/)**

change `$('#tot').html()` to `$('#tot').val()`

If you require the selected items text, then use;

```
var txt = $('#apparelType').find('option:selected').text();
```